# No sound from SoundPool on Sony Xperia Z3

Tags: android, sony, soundpool, sony-xperia

I'm working on an Android app that plays sounds at regular intervals. I'm using the **SoundPool class** for this, and call the method play.

In the emulator it works just fine with a virtual Nexus 5 (API 18 & API 22). It also works for mobiles I've tried from Samsung and HTC. However, I hear **no sound on my Sony Xperia Z3**... And since this is the phone I own it is truly annoying. The issue is repeatable on a friend's Sony Xperia Z3 Compact.

I've tried with both the deprecated SoundPool constructor and the SoundPool.Builder and get the same behavior.

Is there some known Xperia issue? How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of sound files are you using?  I was having problems using .WAV files until I learned that .OGG decoding is more universally supported.  I converted all my sound files to .OGG files and all my problems went away.

Comment: Good suggestion! Yes, I have .WAV files. Will convert them and hope for the best. UPDATE: Yes, using .OGG solved the issue!